# jqueryUI slider- Add a number inside the slider box

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

The question is self-explanatory. How can I add a **number** inside the **slider-box**, so that If I move my slider the value chnges inside the slider-box itself in jQueryUI?

Here is my [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WP29E/181/). I want to add the value inside the `black` slider box.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/WP29E/182/

I added this jquery

```
$('.slider1').on('slide', function(event,ui) {
   var x = $(this).slider('value');
       $('.slider1 .ui-slider-handle').text(x);
});
```

I added a class for each in the html

```
<div class="slider slider1"></div>
<div class="slider slider2"></div>
```

I just did the number for the first slider, but I'm sure you can figure it out from here now!

Comment: The value does not changes, while sliding. Also why the value appears in the extreme left bar? Can I remove that bar?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `slide` property of the object passed to `slider`.

```
slide: function( event, ui ) {
  $(ui.handle).text(ui.value);
}
```

`ui` provides the target object as well as the current value of the slider.

Then to display the initial value:

```
$('.ui-slider-handle').each(function() {
  $(this).text($(this).parent().slider('value'));
});
```

This will set the text of each slider handle to the slider value of its parent (the parent of the `.ui-slider-handle` is the `.slider`). Or, if you want to use ranges, you'll need to find which element you need to pick from `values`:

```
$(this).text($(this).parent().slider('values')[$(this).index()-1]);
```

[JSFiddle for single value](http://jsfiddle.net/WP29E/184/)

[JSFiddle for range](http://jsfiddle.net/WP29E/185/)

Comment: The value appears only upon sliding. Is there a possibility which allows me to have a default value set as 15, which appears in the box when the page loads.

Comment: I updated the answer to set the value when it loads.